# consul json parsing with python

Tags: python, json, consul

I am trying to pull multiple values from consul.
after pulling data using the following code:

`import consul
c = consul.Consul("consulServer")
index, data = c.kv.get("key",recurese=False)
print data`

I am getting the following json in my data list:

`[ {
    'LockIndex': 0,
    'ModifyIndex': 54,
    'Value': '1',
    'Flags': 0,
    'Key': 'test/one',
    'CreateIndex': 54
}, {
    'LockIndex': 0,
    'ModifyIndex': 69,
    'Value': '2',
    'Flags': 0,
    'Key': 'test/two',
    'CreateIndex': 69
}]`

I want to transform this output to key:value json file. for this example it should look like:

`{
  "one": "1",
  "two": "2"
}`

I have two questions:
1. Is there a better way to get multiple values from consul kv?
2. Assuming there is no better way, what is the best way to convert the json from the first example to the second one?

Thanks,

Comment: Show us code you have been trying.

Comment: ```import consul

c = consul.Consul("consulServer")
index, data = c.kv.get("key",recurese=False)

print data```

Comment: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve